# SSG pages in Nux3 prerendered with nitro client only not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, static-site-generation

I have a component that looks like this,

```
<template>
       <ClientOnly>
              <div ref="mini" class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-GB" data-template-id="xxxxx" data-businessunit-id="xxxxxx" data-style-height="115px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light" data-font-family="Poppins">
                     <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
              </div>
       </ClientOnly>
       
</template>

<script setup>

import { onMounted } from 'vue';

const mini = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
       if(process.client) {
              window.Trustpilot?.loadFromElement(mini.value);
              mini.value.style.display = "block";
       }
       
});
</script>
```

and another one that looks like this,

```
<template>
    <ClientOnly>
        <div class="w-full px-2 lg:px-5" :class="[blockBackgroundColour?.class, `block__theme--${blockTheme}`]">
            <h5 v-if="showHeader" class="font-bold text-xlarge leading-32 text-inherit mb-5 text-center">TrustPilot Reviews</h5>
            <div ref="slider" id="slider" class="container mx-auto px-5 lg:px-0 trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-GB" data-template-id="xxxx" data-businessunit-id="xxxxx" data-style-height="240px" data-style-width="100%" :data-theme="TPTheme(tpTheme)" data-stars="4,5" data-review-languages="en">
            </div>
        </div>
    </ClientOnly>
</template>

<script setup>

import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { TPTheme } from '~/helpers/theme';

const slider = ref(null);

const props = defineProps({
    blockData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
});

const { blockBackgroundColour, blockTheme, showHeader } = props.blockData[0];

// add fall back if background colour not set for trustpilot theme 
const tpTheme = blockBackgroundColour?.class || 'block--bg-white';

onMounted(() => {
    if(process.client) {
        window.Trustpilot?.loadFromElement(slider.value);
        slider.value.style.display = "block";
    }
});

</script>
```

they simple do not seem to trigger on prerendered pages, what am I doing wrong I have tried wrapping that in `<ClientOnly />` I have tried checking the process is the client. What other options do I have? It appears that I can only have 1 rendered at anyone time, then if I do a hard refresh both rendered correctly. I am loading the JS in via a plugin,

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
        useHead({
            script: [
                {
                    src: "/scripts/livechat.js",
                },
                {
                    src: "//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js",
                    async: true
                }
            ]
        })
})
```

This is driving me crazy.

Error in the console,

> fs.js:4 No element supplied to "Trustpilot.loadFromElement"

When running the site with `yarn dev` the error is not thrown. It's like its executing before the render?

Comment: In your plugin configuration, is it suffix by `.client`?

Comment: It’s not no, should it be?

Comment: If the plugin you added is only for client, the, it is recommended to suffix it with `.client`

Comment: It does have a client suffix. I have added the error I am getting in the console.